# Gradle Exec now throws "error=2, No such file or directory"

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a repo https://github.com/ahoffer/geotools-tutorials.
I used to be able to run `./gradlew installJar` without error.
A few months have gone by and `./gradlew installJar` produces:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn install:install-file -Dfile="lib/jai_core-1.1.3.jar.zip" -DgroupId=javax.media -DartifactId=jai-core -Dversion=1.1.3 -Dpackaging=jar" (in directory "/projects/geotools-tutorials"): error=2, No such file or directory
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
```

I can copy and paste the commanLine task to the shell and it runs fine:

> /projects/geotools-tutorials$ mvn install:install-file
>   -Dfile="lib/jai_core-1.1.3.jar.zip" -DgroupId=javax.media -DartifactId=jai-core -Dversion=1.1.3 -Dpackaging=jar [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

I do not know why it stopped working or how to get it working again. I am on Ubuntu 19.10.

```
Gradle 5.6.1

Build time:   2019-08-28 02:49:34 UTC
Revision:     b6bd8e7934ca41d9e52610058aa7cb834df81fc4

Kotlin:       1.3.41
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.14 compiled on March 12 2019
JVM:          11.0.5-ea (Ubuntu 11.0.5-ea+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1)
OS:           Linux 5.3.0-24-generic amd64
```

Comment: What is your version of gradle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what version of gradle you were using for that task to have executed successfully, but this is the way to structure that `commandLine`:

```
commandLine 'mvn', 'install:install-file', '-Dfile=lib/jai_core-1.1.3.jar.zip', '-DgroupId=javax.media', '-DartifactId=jai-core', '-Dversion=1.1.3', '-Dpackaging=jar'
```

Tested and works with gradle 5.5